# Matched termination of a microstrip using absorber foam

Tags: pcb, rf, impedance-matching, termination, microstrip

I have open ended microstrips in an RF circuit (operation freq. 18 GHz) and they cause unwanted back reflection into the rest of the circuit.
Now, I wonder if it is possible to eliminate / reduce these reflections without having to solder anything on there (there are a lot of these open ends, so if possible I would try to avoid this) by placing some RF absorber foam on there. In theory, it is made to match air at the top then have a gradual transition to something heavily absorbing. So, if placed "on its side" should it not do the same thing that it normally does to free space radiation to the signal propagating on the microstrip - namely absorbing it while preventing reflections due to some abrupt termination.

Any advice on / experience with this?

Comment: Ask these guys https://www.dmcrf.com/rf-absorbers/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=RF-&-Microwave-Absorbers&utm_term=rf%20foam&utm_device=c&utm_matchtype=p&gclid=CjwKCAjwqIiFBhAHEiwANg9szp9LH_720_m9YjMVwchl6jbAhWPP2PVd9X4sNP5qXse7QBr9fU2xIBoCO1MQAvD_BwEto

Comment: It seems unlikely that the absorber will provide a decent match to the (50 ohm?) transmission line impedance. There will still be an abrupt end to the transmission line and likely an abrupt change in impedance.

Comment: Probably need higher density than foam, perhaps ferrite/carbon-loaded rubber or epoxy. But any amount of any absorber will improve things.

Comment: Are you sure they are unnecessary?  No one would design an 18 GHz system with unnecessary stubs.  Stubs are used for impedance matching and/or filtering.